# Come e quando si usa "scrutinare" e "scrutinio" in ambito scolastico?

Tags: word-usage

Leggendo le notizie sulle elezioni nel mio Paese, ho imparato questo verbo: "scrutinare". A mia sorpresa, però, quando l'ho cercato nel dizionario, ho scoperto che questo verbo e anche il sostantivo "scrutinio" si possono usare pure in ambito scolastico. Mi potreste spiegare in quali situazioni vengono usati, magari facendo qualche esempio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel linguaggio scolastico, [scrutinio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scrutinio/) è la determinazione collegiale del giudizio su ciascun alunno o candidato, e dei voti da assegnargli nelle singole materie, fatta dal consiglio di classe dei professori o dalla commissione esaminatrice: *s. trimestrale, finale; l’esito dello s. è stato soddisfacente*.

**Scrutinare** è l'operazione mediante la quale un'apposita commissione di insegnanti valuta il profitto degli alunni di una classe alla fine di un trimestre, quadrimestre o di un intero anno scolastico.

Gli scrutini incominciano nel momento in cui, a porte chiuse, i professori di una determinata classe si siedono insieme ed aprono il registro, discutendo dell’andamento dei ragazzi. La riunione è presieduta dal dirigente scolastico. La valutazione degli apprendimenti spetta al consiglio di classe con deliberazione assunta, ove necessario, a maggioranza.

L’art. 79 del R.D. 653/1925 prescrive che “I voti si assegnano, su proposta dei singoli professori, in base ad un giudizio brevemente motivato desunto da un congruo numero di interrogazioni e di esercizi scritti, grafici o pratici fatti in casa o a scuola, corretti e classificati durante il trimestre o durante l’ultimo periodo delle lezioni”.

L’ART. 6/2 dell’Ordinanza Ministeriale n. 92 riprende tale contenuto affermando:

“Il docente della disciplina propone il voto in base ad un giudizio motivato desunto dagli esiti di un congruo numero di prove effettuate durante l’ultimo trimestre o quadrimestre e sulla base di una valutazione complessiva dell’impegno, interesse e partecipazione dimostrati nell’intero percorso formativo. La proposta di voto tiene altresì conto delle valutazioni espresse in sede di scrutinio intermedio nonché dell’esito delle verifiche relative ad eventuali iniziative di sostegno e ad interventi di recupero precedentemente effettuati”.

È per tale motivo che i voti sono solo “proposti” dal docente ma ratificati o modificati dal consiglio di classe.